# 2 condition for the radio button option

Tags: php, html, checkbox, radio-button

Im pretty new to php language. Currently Im working on making a form and let user click submit and the output will be sent to my email(using phpmailer).

For now all working OK, but I just want to make a minor tweak where **if user answer YES for the radio button, then the user need to check at least 1 checkbox in order for the form to process**, whereas **if the user answer NO for the radio button, there is no error shown if they dont check the checkbox**. Need some idea on how to tweak the code to make it like that.

The form HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
        <p>Have you worn contact Lens before?</p>
        <input type="radio" name="lenses"  value="Yes"/> Yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="lenses"  value="No"/> No<br>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
        <p>If yes, which type of disposable contact lens have you worn before?</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="disposable_lens[]"  value="Monthly"/> Monthly<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="disposable_lens[]"  value="Daily Disposables"/> Daily Disposables<br>
</div>
```

The PHP

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
if(empty($_POST["lenses"]))
{
    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Lenses is required</label></p>';
}
else
{
    $lenses = clean_text($_POST["lenses"]);
}
if(empty($_POST["disposable_lens"]))
{
    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Disposable_lens is required</label></p>';
}
else
{
    $disposable_lens = array_map('clean_text', $_POST["disposable_lens"]);
```

And this is the phpmailer body message in case you guys want to see

```
$mail->Body = join('', array(
        "Outlet: ",
        $_POST['outlet'],
        "<br/>",
        "Full Name: ",
        $_POST['fullname'],
        "<br/>",
        "Email Address: ",
        $_POST['email'],
        "<br/>",
        "Phone Number:",
        $_POST['contact_no'],
        "<br/>",
        "Have you worn contact lens before?: ",
        $_POST['lenses'],
        "<br/>",
        "If yes, which type of disposable contact lens have you worn before?: ",
        join(', ', $_POST['disposable_lens']),
        "<br/>",
        "Appointment Date ",
        $_POST['date'],
        "<br/>",
        "Appointment Time ",
        $_POST['time']
        ));
```

Comment: You could make a Javascript script, which will add the `disabled` attribute on your checkboxes if "no" is checked.

Comment: Not sure if that `join` is the fastest way to set the e-mail body in PHP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function show() { 
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");    
        x.style.display = "block";   
}

function hide(){
 var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");    
        x.style.display = "none";   
}
```

```css
#myDIV { display:none; }
```

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
        <p>Have you worn contact Lens before?</p>
        <input onclick="show()" type="radio" name="lenses"  value="Yes"/> Yes<br>
        <input onclick="hide()"type="radio" name="lenses"  value="No"/> No<br>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="myDIV">
        <p>If yes, which type of disposable contact lens have you worn before?</p>
        <input  type="checkbox" name="disposable_lens[]"  value="Monthly"/> Monthly<br>
        <input  type="checkbox" name="disposable_lens[]"  value="Daily Disposables"/> Daily Disposables<br>
</div>
<?php echo $error; ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

```
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
if(empty($_POST["lenses"])) {
    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Lenses is required</label></p>';
}

else {
    if($_POST["lenses"] == "Yes" && empty($_POST["disposable_lens"])) {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Disposable_lens is required</label></p>';
    }
    else{
        $disposable_lens[] =  $_POST["disposable_lens"];
    }   
}

if(!empty($_POST["disposable_lens"])) {
    $disposablelens = implode(",",$disposable_lens[0]);
}
    if(empty($error)) {
        echo "Have you worn contact Lens before? ".$_POST["lenses"]."<br>";
        echo "If yes, which type of disposable contact lens have you worn before? ".$disposablelens;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in php... You can add some javascript as @Rameleu sugested in the comments. That will improve user experience.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    // Check if lenses is yes or no (not emty)
    if(empty($_POST["lenses"])) {
        $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Lenses is required</label></p>';
    }
    else {
        // When lenses is yes and no disposable lens is checked
        if($_POST["lenses"] == "yes" && count($_POST["disposable_lens"]) == 0) {
            $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Disposable_lens is required</label></p>';
        }
        // When lenses is yes and one (or more) disposable lens is checked
        elseif($_POST["lenses"] == "yes" && count($_POST["disposable_lens"]) > 0) {
            $lenses = clean_text($_POST["lenses"]);
            $disposable_lens = array_map('clean_text', $_POST["disposable_lens"]);
        }
        // When lenses is no
        elseif($_POST["lenses"] == "no") {
            $lenses = clean_text($_POST["lenses"]);

            // Can they still use the checkboxes? Then you'ld need this
            if(count($_POST["disposable_lens"]) > 0) {
                $disposable_lens = array_map('clean_text', $_POST["disposable_lens"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. but got new issue though regarding phpmailer setting. If I pick NO and not check any checkbox, there are two errors coming but my mail still send.

The errors are :-

Notice: Undefined index: disposable_lens in on line 140

Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed in on line 140

Can I just hide this error as the mail is working fine?

Comment: Email should not send if any error. So wrap the email function in an if statement and prevent it from being sent in first place :)